# VestaCP Cannot Open After Install

Tags: putty, vps, centos6

I use CentOS 6 in my VPS, and then I install VestaCP (Putty). Installation is finish, without error, but the IP cannot open. (https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8086), Anybody can solve this case?

Answer (score 1):

The correct port after install is 8083